# remove 'idle time' while keeping on pressing a key

Tags: javascript, keydown, event-listener, keyup

When you write something and you keep pressing a key (let's say 'a') it will write down 'a', then your pc will wait for about 200ms ('idle time') and only then it will copiously write 'a' for as long as you hold the key.
For various reasons (mainly game controls) I want to remove that 'idle time', how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just want to start a timing loop when the key is pressed, do whatever and then end the timing loop when you let the key go: here's how I'd go about doing it:

get a variable that knows whether or not the key is down then add a keydown event listener to whatever you're pressing the key on that triggers a timing loop function that stops when the variable is false, and add a keyup event listener that makes the variable false, like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){if(!pressed)loop(e)});
function loop(e){
    if(pressed) window.setTimeout(function(){loop(e), 20 /*just insert the ms between each loop*/};
    //do stuff with the key, using the 'e' parameter;
}
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){pressed=false});
```

Of course you'd have to do this for every key, but you could use automatically generated arrays, and since you mainly use it for game controls I assume you don't need many of those things, so this should work nicely for you